# SIM cards with static IP address

Tags: ios, testing, lte, apn, 4g

I am building an iOS App for my employer and we are in the testing phase.

We have to use a third party service and access their Staging environment.

In order to access their service, for security reason, they need to whitelist the IP addresses of the devices that we'll use for testing.

How can I proceed? Are there providers in the US that offers an APN with static IP addresses? Would that work?

**One more thing:**

We can't use a VPN. The third party service has an SDK installed on our devices and blocks the App if a VPN or other spoofing solutions are detected.

The third party service is a geolocation service.

Comment: Your best bet would probably to use a VPN client on your iOS device so that it accesses the Internet via a fixed Internet connection that you control

Comment: @Paulw11 forgot to mention - I can't use a VPN. The third party service has an SDK installed on our devices and blocks the App if a VPN or other spoofing solution is detected. It's a geolocation service. Question updated with these details, thanks.

Comment: A properly installed VPN should be invisible to the app, but if they won't let you use a VPN and they won't let you use a non-whitelisted IP address then you are probably limited to wifi testing.  You would have to ask the carriers if they provide a fixed IP solution. Asking here is off topic

Comment: @Paulw11 The geolocation service performs about 300 checks on the device. It's a highly reliable service used by major companies. I know that other competitors managed to perform this type of testing using an internet provider with an APN that offered SIMs with static IP addresses but I can't find enough information on the internet. I am still waiting replies from some internet providers. Thanks

Comment: You could probably use a private APN that delivers the traffic directly to your network so that you can access the internet via a fixed gateway, but you need to work with the carriers on this.  It is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks for your help @Paulw11

Comment: A quick google turned up this https://developer.att.com/technical-library/apns/custom-apns

Comment: @Paulw11 this may be useful too - "JT Fixed Public Model":
https://blog.jtiotsims.com/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-fixed-ip-sim-card